# Windows pods can't resolve services

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, dns, dnsmasq

I have 2 node K8 cluster (1 linux + 1 win node).

For windows I'm using 1803 version. The issue I'm facing with is that Pods in Windows node can't resolve domain of services created on K8 cluster and which points to Pods on linux machine.

I can run container inside Windows node, tried with iis and containers are started successfully but they cannot resolve dns -> if you try nslookup or even ping clusterIP od service.

On linux node everything is working fine and pods see each other. Any suggestions or doubts where is the problem?

Comment: can you check if all kube-dns instances are up? `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

Comment: Yeah, kube-dns instance is up but as I see that pod is on on linux node. Should they be on each node at least one?

Comment: probably, but I am not sure, maybe this guide will help - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/